# WPF NotSupportedException : "pixel format not supported"

Tags: wpf, exception, png

I got an exception in my WPF window constructor on call : "InitializeComponent()"

The exception is NotSupportedException : "pixel format not supported"

I didn't find any info on the internet.

Why this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential cause for the "pixel format not supported" exception is an image with color space "Indexed".  This means that a pixel value is not represented by three (R,G,B) bytes (which would be the case in the usual RGB color space), but by a single-byte index into a color table.
The color space of an image can be checked and changed e.g. with Gimp via the "Image /Mode" menu.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to let people know that the bug come from a buggy PNG image file used in a MenuItem.

To solve my problem I open the failing PNG in Paint.net and overide the buggy one.... No more exception.

Note: The problem appears only when you break on any exception. Otherwise everything seems ok and the icon (.png) show properly on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Tracked this exception down to a PNG image in my application.  After examining the image in Photoshop, I noticed that it had its color Mode set to Indexed.  Changing it to RGB fixed the problem, and no more exceptions.
You can check/change the mode in Photoshop as following:

Image -> Mode -> RGB

Also, this exception will only happen if you enable it in Visual Studio:

Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions (check)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Your additional information is very welcome, but I will let the answer as is because I think Rose also give proper problem explanation. I'm sure people will appreciate this additional info.

Comment: No worries, I wasn't looking for points, just wanted to let people know how to fix the problem.